# Rewriting a trigonometric inequality (including a parameter)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How is it possible to rewrite these equations?

$\sin{x}- \cos{x} ≤ \mu(\cos{x} + \sin{x}) \implies \tan{}x ≤ \frac{1 + \mu}{1 - \mu}$

and

$\cos{x}- \sin{x} ≤ \mu(\cos{x} + \sin{x}) \implies \tan{}x ≥ \frac{1 - \mu}{1 + \mu}$

---

from the physics textbook *Classical Mechanics by D. Morin* Chapter I: Statics p.I-4

Comment: FYI $\;\mu = $ `\mu`; $\;\implies = \;$ `\implies`

Comment: The technique that you need to know is called "componendo and divideno". It can be found in  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$sin(x)-cos(x) \le \mu sin(x) + \mu cos(x)\\sin(x)- \mu sin(x) \le  cos(x) + \mu cos(x)\\$

Factor $sin(x)$ on the LHS and the $cos(x)$ from the RHS and divide by $cos(x)$ and $1- \mu$

This assumes positivity for $cos(x)$ and $1- \mu$ so you might want to check on that. The second inequality can be solved in much the same way.

Comment: `\cos x`: $\cos x$, $\quad$ `\sin x` : $\sin x$.

Comment: Thanks! Haha, always seems so simple when you get the answer :) In this case just needed to calculate it out :| feel so retarded... Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\frac{\cos x}{\cos x}+1=\frac{sin x-\cos x}{\cos x}+1\leq\mu\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{\cos x}+1=\\ =\mu+1+\mu\tan x$$
so we get
$$\tan x-\mu\tan x\leq\mu+1$$
and then
$$\tan x\leq \frac{1+\mu}{1-\mu}$$

Comment: Thanks for solving the problem! 
Your answer just seems a little far fetched... The other one is rather logical.